# How to catch notifydatasetchanged of Android ListView?

Tags: android, listview

I have write a ListView Adapter extend BaseAdapter. In this adapter I can click the Button in the ListView Row to remove the row item from datasource.

Now I get a problem. There is a TotalAmount outside the ListView, when the row item removed, this TotalAmount not change.

How can I make it change while I remove the row item in my adapter?

Comment: I have made it.

I write the adapter into the Activity as a inner class. So the click event can access the outer class' method.

Answer (score 0):

in your provider, when exec delete successfully ,you should notify

```
getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(Your_URI, null);
```

register a observer in your TotalAmount

```
getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(uri, bool, observer)
```